# Run Pipeline Button disabled

Tags: pipeline

I am new to Azure DevOps Pipeline.  I have connected to a bitbucket repo and running against master for the build works fine.

I am trying to manually run against a branch.  I choose the correct branch from branch/tag and I see that the "Run" button is disabled.  If I choose "master" it is enabled.

What am I missing?

Comment: I'd like to know the answer to this too!

Answer (score 1):

So you may not have the same issue I had but it's definitely one cause.

Lets say you start with a branch called "master" and a build pipeline called "Build Master" which uses an YAML file called "azure-pipelines.yml".

If like me you created a feature branch **before** setting up the build for the master branch then your feature branch won't have the azure-pipelines.yml file.

To make the "Run" enabled make sure when using the "Build Master" pipeline that the branch you are trying to build has an azure-pipelines.yml file in as it will use that yml file for the build and **not** the one in the "master" branch. If it doesn't then I just created one in the branch and copied over the contents from the master branch.

Hope that makes sense.